# Why C++ thread calls destructor multiple times?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I am curious why a simple c++ program like the one attached below calls destructor of the work1 object multiple times while it is being processed in std::thread. Why is that it calls destructor multiple times.

```
    class work1 {
    public:
    work1(int x_) : x(x_) {
        ++count;
        std::cout<<"\n[WORKER1] Ctor : "<<count<<std::endl;
    }

    ~work1() {
        std::cout<<"\n[WORKER1] Dtor : "<<count<<std::endl;
    }

    void operator() () {
        for(int i =0; i < x; ++i) {
            std::cout<<"[WORKER1] Printing this :: "<<i<<std::endl;
        }
    }

    private:
        int x;
        static int count;
    };

int main()
{
    int local_main=5;
    std::thread t((work1(local_main)));
    t.join();    
    std::cout<<"\n[MAIN] From main thread..."<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The above code produces the following output:

```
[WORKER1] Ctor : 1
[WORKER1] Dtor : 1
[WORKER1] Dtor : 1
[WORKER1] Printing this :: 0
[WORKER1] Printing this :: 1
[WORKER1] Printing this :: 2
[WORKER1] Printing this :: 3
[WORKER1] Printing this :: 4
[WORKER1] Dtor : 1
[MAIN] From main thread...
```

Comment: Since we don't have a [mcve] we can't really tell what's happening or help you figure out why and how to fix any problems. Also please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: It's now clearer, and it's simply a case of *copying* (or moving). The thread needs a copy of the function to call, and in your case each copy is a copy of the object (which leads to copy- or move-construction) followed by destructions of possible temporary objects.

Comment: how can we control this and rectify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::thread` makes a copy of the argument by calling the copy constructor. Implement the copy constructor to observe the copies:

```
class work1 {
public:
    work1(int x_) : x(x_) {
        ++count;
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ' ' << count << '\n';
    }

    work1(work1 const& other)
        : x(other.x)
    {
        ++count;
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ' ' << count << '\n';
    }

    work1& operator=(work1 const& other)
    {
        x = other.x;
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ' ' << count << '\n';
        return *this;
    }

    ~work1() {
        --count;
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << ' ' << count << '\n';
    }

    void operator() () {
        for(int i =0; i < x; ++i) {
            std::cout<<"[WORKER1] Printing this :: "<<i<<std::endl;
        }
    }

private:
    int x;
    static int count;
};

int work1::count;

int main() {
    int local_main=5;
    std::thread t((work1(local_main)));
    t.join();
}
```

Outputs:

```
work1::work1(int) 1
work1::work1(const work1&) 2
work1::work1(const work1&) 3
work1::~work1() 2
work1::~work1() 1
[WORKER1] Printing this :: 0
[WORKER1] Printing this :: 1
[WORKER1] Printing this :: 2
[WORKER1] Printing this :: 3
[WORKER1] Printing this :: 4
work1::~work1() 0
```

If you'd like to avoid copying pass a reference to your functional object the thread using `std::ref`:

```
int main() {
    work1 w{5};
    std::thread t(std::ref(w));
    t.join();
}
```

Outputs:

```
work1::work1(int) 1
[WORKER1] Printing this :: 0
[WORKER1] Printing this :: 1
[WORKER1] Printing this :: 2
[WORKER1] Printing this :: 3
[WORKER1] Printing this :: 4
work1::~work1() 0
```

Comment: But dont you think tossing references of the same object is not a good idea as other threads will also be holding a reference to the same object. Isnt this true ? Sorry for being argumentative but I need to clarify these few concepts.

Comment: @AnubhavRohatgi Thread having its own copy is the safest. With a reference the object must be kept alive while the other thread uses it.